# Не могу подключится к веб-сокету

Tags: websocket, socket.io

Решил попробовать веб-сокеты. Выбрал socket.io. На сервере у меня php, поэтому выбрал такое решение - [github](https://github.com/walkor/phpsocket.io)

Но никак не могу настроить. Сервер вроде запустился, но достучаться до него не могу. Может кто сталкивался?

Код сервера

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$io = new \PHPSocketIO\Socket(2021);
$io->on('connection', function($connection)use($io){
    echo "new connection coming\n";
});
\Workerman\Worker::runAll();
```

В JS подключаюсь

```
var socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:2021');
socket.on('connect', function(){
    console.log('connect success');
});
```

заменив 127.0.0.1 на ip сервера

Comment: покажите код, мы не ванги

Comment: добавил в описание

Comment: проверил порты. и хотя пишет, что сервер запущен - не нашел кто слушает 2021

Comment: Вывод `sudo netstat -pan | grep ":2021"` покажите.

Comment: у вас опечатка - замените к коде php `Socket(2021)` на `SocketIO(2021)`, и всё заработает

Comment: спасибо, заработало